# Occupancy grid not displaying in Rviz

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, ros-melodic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a custom model which I created from my xacro files and I can move around using a teleop node. BUT I now want to map a virtual room and I added the AMCL and Gmapping nodes to my launch file but I notice a number of things in Rziv which are definately NOT right :

1. The occupancy grid is not visible in Rviz so the room is not being mapped
2. The /map topic has no data published into it
3. 2D pose estimates in Rviz does not show particle filters

The following is my launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

    <!-- PARAMETERS -->
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(find sweep_bot)/urdf/cleaner.xacro"/>

    <!-- RVIZ -->
    <node name='robot_state_publisher' pkg='robot_state_publisher' type='robot_state_publisher'/>
    <node name='joint_state_publisher_gui' pkg='joint_state_publisher_gui' type='joint_state_publisher_gui'/>
    <node name='rviz' pkg='rviz' type='rviz'/>

    <!-- GAZEBO -->
    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/willowgarage_world.launch"></include>
    <node name='sweeper_bot' pkg='gazebo_ros' type='spawn_model' args='-urdf -model sweeper -param robot_description'/>

    <!--- Run AMCL --> 
    <include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_omni.launch" />

    <!-- GMAPPING -->
    <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="gmapping" output="screen"></node>

    <!-- Move Base -->
    <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen"/>

</launch>
```

My /tf and /odom topics show data is being published into them.

My terminal prints the following message repeatedly:

```
[ WARN] [1612313212.923369324, 5.005000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: source_frame base_link does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1.
```

[image: image description]
As shown in the image above, rviz shows the laser detects obstacles but the occupancy grid does not display.

**My questions :**

- I know my /tf is generated from joints as defined in my urdf file(s) but **is the data in the /odom topic also auto generated from the urdf ?**
- Can anyone give me any insight into why my /map topic is empty ?

**UPDATE **

Below is the tf :
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370839/occupancy-grid-not-displaying-in-rviz/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2021-02-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2021-02-02**:
First `AMCL` is for localization when you already know the map and `gmapping` is for localization while creating the map so they shouldn't be used at the same time. You should try to create the map first using only `gmapping` and then use `AMCL` with the map you've created.

Now you might have something wrong with your TFs, can you show us your tf tree ? (Using `rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree`)

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2021-02-02**:
@Delb: Thanks for your input. I added my tf tree as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out.

The GMapping node was missing configuration parameters which would tell it agongst other things, what topic to publish map data to. See below :

```
<node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="gmapping" output="screen">
   <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
   <param name="base_frame" value="chasis"/> 
   <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/> 
</node>
```

All available parameters are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping.

---

Originally posted by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) with karma: 247 on 2021-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

/odom topics are not automatically generated by urdf.
For example, you need to use `diff_drive_controller` to generate /odom topics from urdf.

Also, even if you can generate an /odom topic, it may not create a map.

Even if you can generate an /odom topic, the map may not be created, because `amcl` and `gmapping` are not usually handled at the same time.
`amcl` is a package that uses `/map` and `/scan` for localization.
`gmapping` is a package that uses `/scan` to localize while issuing `/map`.

1. Generate /map by running `gmapping`without using `amcl`.
2. Save it with `map_saver`.
3. Read the saved map with `map_server` and publish a /map topic.
4. Localization with `amcl`.

You can probably get what you want by proceeding as follows.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-02-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2021-02-02**:
I appreciate your comments. There is a lot I don't know so please bare with me.

The AMCL node in the launch file is commented out of my current build BUT I still find the occupancy grid does not display in Rviz.

Also, isn't the **diff_drive_controller** meant for a two wheeled robot ? My robot is four wheeled.

I added my tf tree above if that would help clarify things.

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-02-04**:
I'm glad to hear that it has been resolved.
diff_drive_controller seems to be a node for motorcycles. ( I've only used it on two wheels. )
However, there seems to be a way to use it on four wheels.

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2021-02-04**:
@Miura: Thank you for your input. I've only ever hear of the diff_drive_controller used on robots like the turtlebot 3 in a side-by-side configuration. It would be interesting to see if it can be used for motocycles.